# Intution behind weighted random sampler in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to use `WeightedRandomSampler` for handling imbalance in the dataset (class1: 2555, class 2: 227, class 3: 621, class 4: 2552 images). However, I debugged the steps but the intuition behind it is not clear to me. My target labels are in form of one-hot encoded vectors as below.

```
train_labels.head(5)
```

[image: Target Labels]

I converted the labels to class index as:

```
labels = np.argmax(train_labels.loc[:, 'none':'both'].values, axis=1)
train_labels = torch.from_numpy(labels)
train_labels
tensor([0, 0, 1,  ..., 1, 0, 0])
```

Below are the steps, I used to calculate for the weighted random sampler. Please correct me if I am wrong with the interpretation of any steps.

1. Count the number of samples per class in the dataset

   ```
   class_sample_count = np.array(train_labels.value_counts()) 
   class_sample_count
   array([2555, 2552,  621,  227])
   ```
2. Calculate the weight associated with each class

   ```
   weight = 1. / class_sample_count 
   weight
   array([0.00039139, 0.00039185, 0.00161031, 0.00440529])
   ```
3. Calculate the weight for each of the samples in the dataset.

   ```
   samples_weight = np.array(weight[train_labels])
   print(samples_weight[1], samples_weight[2] )
   0.0003913894324853229 0.00039184952978056425
   ```

Convert the np.array to tensor

```
     tensor([0.0004, 0.0004, 0.0004,  ..., 0.0004, 0.0004, 0.0004],
     dtype=torch.float64)
```

After conversion to tensor, all the samples appear to have the same value in all four entries? Then how does Weighted Random Sampling is helping to deal with the imbalanced dataset?

I will be grateful for the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are computing the weights on the one-hot encodings, and since there are four components (four classes) you end up with four identical weights per instance after the indexing `weight[train_labels]`. The fact that you have identical weights is perfectly fine because each instance should be assigned a unique weight. To the sampler, this weight corresponds to the probability of picking this instance. If a given class is prominent in the dataset, the associated frequency (*i.e.* the weight) will be low, and as such instances of that class will have a lower probability of getting sampled from the dataset.

With a fairly large number of samples, the goal with this weighting scheme is to have a balanced sampling even though class representations are imbalanced.

If you stick with one-hot encodings, you can just pick the first column:

```
>>> sample_weights = np.array(weight[train_labels])[:,0]
```

Then use [`WeightedRandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler) to construct a sampler:

```
>>> sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(sample_weights, len(train_labels))
```

Finally you can plug it into a dataloader:

```
>>> DataLoader(dataset, batch_size, sampler=sampler)
```

Comment: I converted one-hot encoding to class indices. However, still I get the same single value of 0.004 for every label. Which means the weight is the same for classes irrespective of the frequency of images in them.  How this weight is oversampling the minority class? The number of images for each class is still the same. How same probability of all the classes is helping the imbalanced dataset? Since the underlying no. of images for the majority class is more and less for the minority class.

Comment: Can you show the modification you applied to convert ohe to class indices, by editing your question above

Comment: I have edited the main post. The class labels now are: 0,1,2,3

Comment: You are only printing the first and last three instances which either have label `0` or label `1`, both have similar weights. I recommend you look at some other instances, or try this to get a better view: `torch.unique(samples_weight)`, you will see ;)

Comment: This is the tensor I got with torch.unique(samples_weight): tensor([0.0004, 0.0004, 0.0016, 0.0044], dtype=torch.float64). Each of the values is unique :). Now for the intuition: the sampler picks the labels with higher weight more frequently in batch than the samples with lower weight? So, overall in a batch, the sampling is balanced.

Comment: I computed the weighted random sampler from the original dataset. After that, I split the dataset into the train and validation sets. For both sets, the same sampler should be used. right? As it gives the weight is computed from the overall distribution in the original set.

Comment: If the train/validation split is random then you can compute the weights from the whole dataset, the stats should not be so different from that of the train set. For validation it does not matter whether you use a sampler: you should validate on your whole data so either way, the result will be the same. It only matters for the train set.